# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'TypeIt'. import call expects exactly one argument

Tags: javascript, html, import

I am creating my first website, and I am trying to use the type it library. However, whenever I try to import it into my script file, it gives me the above error. This is my code so far:

Index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <span id="element">Here is a string.</span>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

script.js file:

```
import TypeIt from 'typeit';

var instance = new TypeIt('#element', {
    strings: ['This is my string!']
});
```

Here is the folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using any module bundler then you need to add the following  tag before your to your html file:

```
    <script src="/node_modules/typeit/dist/typeit.min.js"></script>
```

Also, remove the import statement in your script.js file and make sure that typeit.min.js is loaded before your script.js file.

Comment: I added that to the top of the body, but now I'm getting these two errors: [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (typeit.min.js, line 0)
[Error] Did not load script at 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/typeit.min.js' because non script MIME types are not allowed when 'X-Content-Type: nosniff' is given.

Comment: that is because you did not specifiy the correct path. If you could take a screenshot of your folder structure where we can see where your html, and typeit.min.js files are, we can help you correct your path.

Comment: I added a screenshot to the question! The typeit.min.js file is in the node_modules folder.

Comment: <script src="/node_modules/any_directories_in_between//typeit.min.js"></script>

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi! Just a quick tip about loading TypeIt in this way. I recommend using the free CDN link. This way, you'll have better performance and won't need to have your node_modules directory in production. Here's the CDN link for the latest version: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typeit@5.10.2/dist/typeit.min.js

Comment: Also, I made TypeIt. Thanks for using it!