# Unexpected identifier 'axios'. import call expects exactly one argument

Tags: api, import, axios

Here is my js code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const quotes = document.querySelector('.quotes');

const getResults = async () => {

    try {

        const res = await axios('http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1');

        quotes.innerHTML = res.data[0].content;

        console.log(res.data[0].content);

    } catch(err) {

        console.log(err);

    }

}
getResults();
```

It yields the following error: `Unexpected identifier 'axios'. import call expects exactly one argument`.
I am running it in browser and I am not using any bundler, any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: You may want to check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51461495/syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier-typeit-import-call-expects-exactly-one-arg

Answer (score 0):

Try using the methods for the different http verbs for example:

```
const res = await axios.get('http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1');
```

Comment: Still it is not working. Again nothing is displayed on the browser and in the console 'SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'axios'. import call expects exactly one argument.' pops up.

Answer (score 0):

Without any transpiler or bundler you will need to include `axios` in your html file with the following code:

```
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

And load it before the file containing the script you want to execute.